# Qt5 JSON parsing from QByteArray

Tags: c++, parsing, qt5, qjson

I have QByteArray,contains this JSON

```
{"response":
      {"count":2,
         "items":[
             {"name":"somename","key":1"},
             {"name":"somename","key":1"}
]}}
```

Need to parse and get the required data:

```
  QJsonDocument itemDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(answer);
  QJsonObject itemObject = itemDoc.object();
  qDebug()<<itemObject;
  QJsonArray itemArray = itemObject["response"].toArray();
  qDebug()<<itemArray;
```

First debug displays the contents of all QByteArray, recorded in itemObject, second debug does not display anything.

Must i parse this otherwise,or why this method does not work?

Comment: What is and where do you declare audioDoc?

Comment: @Merlin069 sorry,just a typo on the site, corrected

Answer (score 7):

You either need to know the format, or work it out by asking the object about its type. This is why [QJsonValue](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html) has functions such as isArray, toArray, isBool, toBool, etc.

If you know the format, you can do something like this: -

```
// get the root object
QJsonDocument itemDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(answer);
QJsonObject rootObject = itemDoc.object();

// get the response object
QJsonValue response = rootObject.value("response");
QJsonObject responseObj = response.toObject();

// print out the list of keys ("count")
QStringList keys = responseObj.keys();
foreach(QString key, keys)
{
    qDebug() << key; 
}

// print the value of the key "count")
qDebug() << responseObj.value("count");

// get the array of items
QJsonValue itemArrayValue = responseObj.value("items");

// check we have an array
if(itemArrayValue.isArray())
{
    // get the array as a JsonArray
    QJsonArray itemArray = itemArrayValue.toArray();
}
```

If you don't know the format, you'll have to ask each QJsonObject of its type and react accordingly. It's a good idea to check the type of a QJsonValue before converting it to its rightful object such as array, int etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with qt APIs in particular, but in general JSON objects cannot be coerced into arrays unless they are JSON arrays (ex: the value for "items").

Perhaps you want something like:

```
QJsonObject itemObject = audioDoc.object();
QJsonObject responseObject = itemObject["response"].toObject();
QJsonArray itemArray = responseObject["items"].toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you,you're right. But must be added to the end `QJsonObject responseObject = itemObject["response"]` method `toObject()`,it prompted me compiler :)